# Can not get the javascript "show hide" div code to work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, show-hide

I **CANNOT** use jQuery on this project (client policy).

My html code is:

```
<div style="display:none" id="dvAnswer<%#Eval("num")%>" class="TextFontBold">A: <%#Eval("answer") %></div>
<a id="btn<%#Eval("num")%>" href="javascript:toggle();">show answer</a>
```

Javascript code is:

```
    function toggle() {
            var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
            var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
            if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                text.innerHTML = "show";
            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                text.innerHTML = "hide";
            }
    }
```

I cannot get this code to work.
Any suggestions to resolving this?

Comment: You don't actually have elements named "toggleText" or "displayText", yet that's what the JavasScript is looking for. Perhaps show us what the `div`/`a` elements look like *after* they've been sent to the browser (view source on the page after it renders).

Comment: You don't have any element with the ids `toggleText` or `displayText`

Comment: My div is dynamically named id="dvAnswer<%#Eval("num")%>" and so is the button that calls the toggle function id="btn<%#Eval("num")%>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to pass two references to your toggle function, one to the target, and one to itself:

```
<div style="display:none" id="dvAnswer<%#Eval("num")%>" class="TextFontBold">A: <%#Eval("answer") %></div>
<a id="btn<%#Eval("num")%>" href="javascript://" onclick="toggle('dvAnswer<%#Eval("num")%>',this);">show answer</a>
```

(plus, it's is good practice to use `onclick`, not `href` for inline javascript)

Then pass these references to your function:

```
function toggle(target,me) {
            var ele = document.getElementById(target);
            var text = me
            if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                text.innerHTML = "show";
            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                text.innerHTML = "hide";
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you were using jQuery, which is worth learning, you can do this in two lines of code and not have to pass any parameters at all.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I agree, but the client specifically mentioned no Jquery. Thanks very much for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of your element is not **toggleText** and I don't see an **displayText** element either.

Answer (score 1):

First your div doesn't have id="toggleText" and no id="displayText"

so what you need to do is create small algorithm   for that

```
function toggle(lnk) {
           var num = lnk.getAttribute('id').toString().replace('btn','');
            var ele = document.getElementById('dvAnswer'+num);
            if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                lnk.innerHTML = "show";
            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                lnk.innerHTML = "hide";
            }
    }
```

and your html should look like this

```
<div style="display:none" id="dvAnswer<%#Eval("num")%>" class="TextFontBold">A: <%#Eval("answer") %></div>
<a id="btn<%#Eval("num")%>" onclick="toggle(this); return false;" href="#">show answer</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are calling elements by the wrong IDs. In your HTML, I do not see 'toggleText' or 'displayText' IDs for any of your elements.

The ID looks dynamic from your example. Perhaps just pass the object reference in your function:

```
function toggle(objRef) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(objRef);
        var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
            text.innerHTML = "show";
        }
        else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            text.innerHTML = "hide";
        }
}
```

And HTML of:

```
<a id="btn<%#Eval("num")%>" href="javascript:toggle("dvAnswer<%#Eval("num")%>");">show answer</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your id's in html are not the same as requested by javascript ? This "should" work

```
<div style="display:none" id="toggleText" class="TextFontBold">A:<%#Eval("answer") %></div>
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show answer</a>
```